# How to add widget inside class by function?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to add a number of widgets to a class. I cannot directly use  `add_widget` as the number is unknown at the beginning. I tried to use function but failed.

in.py

```
class ProductPage(Screen):
    def update_count(self): # I call this function in the previous screen after pressing a button
        global count
        count = len(result_eName)

    def add_productbutton(self): # I call this function in the previous screen after pressing a button
        for i in range(count):
            self.ids.background.add_widget(Button(text = str(i)))
            # refer to the layout where I want to add widget
```

in.kv

```
<ProductPage>:
    BoxLayout:
        id: background
        Button:
            text: "trying"
```

How can I add widgets to the 'ProductPage' screen after getting the value of count in the previous screen? Or am I in the wrong direction?

Comment: Are you getting any error messages? Try sprinkling `print('count =', count)` around your code to help see what is happening.

Comment: I can get into `add_productbutton` function, for loop and  the correct count value. But I cannot add any widget to the background layout.

Comment: It didn't show any error either.

Comment: Sorry, can't help you without more information. Please post a [mcve].